# How can we get Function name from Spack Pointer(reg/SP) on Linux?

Tags: linux, callstack, ptrace, cpu-registers

i am using ptrace to get information related to Callstack on Linux.
i can retrieve Spack Pointer to my stack using register returned by ptarces.
but using this stack pointer how can i retrieve information related to Function name and signature of current call stack?

are there any Linux APIs to traverse this callstack?

please help.. i am looking for it from last few days...

thanks in advance
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to get is a list of code addresses - that of the currently executing function, and the return addresses going back up the call chain.

On x86, the `%eip` register will contain a memory address within the code of the currently-executing function.  The `%ebp` register will point at the location on the stack where the previous value of `%ebp` is stored, followed by the return value.  You need to follow that chain of `%ebp` values, recording the return addresses as you go.

You then need to read the DWARF debugging information in the binary file you're debugging to resolve code addresses back to function names.

Note that backtraces can only be done reliably if the code is compiled with frame pointers.

Comment: What is the significance of these pointers as i get these values from register? How this chain can be followed -
#define BP rbp /*Frame pointer*/
#define SP rsp /*Stack pointer*/
#define IP rip /*Program counter*/
i am new to this concept. Could you plz guide?

Comment: The first thing that happens when a function is entered is that the current value of the frame pointer is pushed onto the stack.  Then, the frame pointer is set to the current value of the stack pointer.  So, working backwards, you can use the current frame pointer to find the location of the previous frame pointer and the return value.

Comment: Hi caf, Thanks for your answers. but i am confused here..
let me tell you what all information i am having about my callstack.
i have a pointer of the register structure, which has these three pointers in it. i.e. stack pointer, program counter and frame pointer and other general pointers. now as i want to traverse stack to get addresses from each frame.

Comment: Now my question is, How do i travese backword from the stack as i dont have any Function to traverse. i need to calculated the offeset between the stack frames or something like that...
how do i calculated this offset distance? 
can i substract this from Stack pointer to get previous Frame pointer?
let me know if you want more information from me.

Comment: again one more point.. as i want to look for Function name in symbol table by the Function address from this stack, which pointer from this would give me the Function address of current executing stack.

Comment: Look at the content of the frame pointer.  That's a pointer into the target processes stack.  If you follow that pointer, by looking it up in the address space of the target process (with `PTRACE_PEEK`), you'll find the *previous* value of the frame pointer.  Repeat that to traverse your way up the call stack.

Comment: Thanks caf. this really helped. i am facing a case where all my base pointer values are same when i read those with PEEKDATA. it is the case with Tomcat process. what does it mean. what should be the reason? is this case possible? with the simple C application i get the correct results as i expected.

Comment: @Sandeep: Possible the process was compiled without frame pointers (or you've made a mistake implementing it).  This is common for an optimising compile on i386, because the architecture lacks registers.  If you can compile Tomcat yourself, make sure it's not compiled with `-fomit-frame-pointer`.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using libunwind in this case. It provides a good API for traversal of call-stack. It depends on presence of .eh_frame header in the object file.It can be used both in local and remote(your use case) contexts. Stack unwinding does not depend on DWARF information or debug builds.

Comment: i could not find the library of libunwind compatible to my Linux. Where can i download from.

Comment: is ".eh_frame header" header auto generated while compilation? what do you think? which object file you are talking about?